# Can i trigger a firebase function with a XMLHttpRequest from a single Webpage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-functions, cross-domain

```
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "https://us-central1MYFUNCTION", true)
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.send( JSON.stringify({ text: value }) )
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function (res) {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                console.log(res)
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log('success')
                } else {
                    console.log(res)
                }
            } else {
                console.log('not ready')
            }
        }
```

Hi im trying to trigger a firebase function with a XMLHttpRequest but im getting error code 400.
What am i doing wrong?
thanks in advance

Comment: Try testing this with postman. Does it work?

Comment: hi im new to js and server requests, i will look into the tool. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Also, you have to call the right type cloud function that way. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: Another useful thing that you could do is to try with curl (to try different configurations of requests that you can make to your endpoint) or if you can successfully trigger the app from a browser, you could try out Burp, this tool can intercept the successful request and you can also check and make other requests with it. Other useful tool is java script and the developer tools from chrome. But basically the 400 error means that your request is missing something or has an option that is not correct, these tools should help you in order to find what is causing the error.